# Binary Classification NN Model Weights not being Trained in PyGAD

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

Here is the code I am writing:
[Fake News Detection Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cPC8HUJ6wra2aT8CYelUAIWeL5PlT6Ic?usp=sharing)

The dataset I use:
[fake_or_real_news](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lB6_H65KIZ3QXnkpXMLe89H0sL3AV4_p/view?usp=sharing)

The glove embedding layer:
[glove.twitter.27B.200d](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XryjSYyg4HTaFUYKAH7UDWC0U4bLZ97w/view?usp=sharing)

I've been trying out PyGAD, a python library for genetic algorithm used on machine learning.

What I want to achieve is fake news detection. What I have done is preprocess the articles, and transform  them into vectors. I use Glove as the embedding layer in the NN. I've tried to train using the NN model without GA, and it worked fine. Then I applied the NN to PyGAD GA following the tutorial: [How To Train Keras Models Using the Genetic Algorithm with PyGAD](https://blog.paperspace.com/train-keras-models-using-genetic-algorithm-with-pygad/), the process seemed to be running fine, but the fitness score wasn't going up at all even after 200 generations. I've tried to change the mutation method and some other hyper parameters, but it doesn't seem to change the outcome. What have I done wrong in the process of building the PyGAD GA model? Most of the PyGAD model settings are the same as the examples in the tutorial above.

To specify the problem I am encountering: Below is the main PyGAD code I am using:

Training input(X_train):

```
array([[ 4981,  2484, 22458, ...,  1019,   135,   892],
   [ 7075,   189, 26439, ...,  4982,    43,     2],
   [ 6168,   335,     2, ...,    73,    27,    73],
   ...,
   [  374,    10,   162, ...,   736,  1744,   484],
   [  500,   118,     2, ...,   348,  2890,  5689],
   [ 8194,  2404,   117, ...,   357,  6332,   186]], dtype=int32)
shape: (3753, 50)
```

Training output(y_train):

```
array([[1., 0.],
   [0., 1.],
   [0., 1.],
   ...,
   [0., 1.],
   [1., 0.],
   [0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
shape:  (3753, )
```

Python code:

```py
import tensorflow.keras
import pygad.kerasga
import numpy
import pygad
def fitness_func(solution, sol_idx):
    global data_inputs, data_outputs, keras_ga, model

    model_weights_matrix = pygad.kerasga.model_weights_as_matrix(model=model, weights_vector=solution)

    model.set_weights(weights=model_weights_matrix)

    predictions = model.predict(data_inputs)
    
    bce = tensorflow.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
    solution_fitness = 1.0 / (bce(data_outputs, predictions).numpy() + 0.00000001)

    return solution_fitness

def callback_generation(ga_instance):
    print("Generation = {generation}".format(generation=ga_instance.generations_completed))
    print("Fitness    = {fitness}".format(fitness=ga_instance.best_solution()[1]))

sequence_length = X_train.shape[1]
filter_sizes = [3,4]
num_filters = 100
drop = 0.4
#the NN 
inputs = Input(shape=(sequence_length,))
embedding = embedding_layer(inputs)
reshape = Reshape((sequence_length,EMBEDDING_DIM,1))(embedding)

conv_0 = Conv2D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[0], EMBEDDING_DIM),activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(reshape)
conv_1 = Conv2D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[1], EMBEDDING_DIM),activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(reshape)

maxpool_0 = MaxPooling2D((sequence_length - filter_sizes[0] + 1, 1), strides=(1,1))(conv_0)
maxpool_1 = MaxPooling2D((sequence_length - filter_sizes[1] + 1, 1), strides=(1,1))(conv_1)

merged_tensor = concatenate([maxpool_0, maxpool_1], axis=1)
flatten = Flatten()(merged_tensor)
reshape = Reshape((2*num_filters,))(flatten)
dropout = Dropout(drop)(flatten)
conc = Dense(40)(dropout)
output = Dense(units=2, activation='sigmoid',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(conc)
#create model
model = Model(inputs, output)
keras_ga = pygad.kerasga.KerasGA(model=model, num_solutions=10)

# Data inputs
data_inputs = X_train
# Data outputs
data_outputs = y_train
data_outputs = tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(data_outputs)
num_generations = 200
num_parents_mating = 8
initial_population = keras_ga.population_weights

ga_instance = pygad.GA(num_generations=num_generations, 
                       num_parents_mating=num_parents_mating, 
                       initial_population=initial_population,
                       fitness_func=fitness_func,
                       on_generation=callback_generation,
                       )
ga_instance.run()
```

This is the result I get after ga_instance.run():

```
Generation = 1
Fitness    = 1.4091019376092528
Generation = 2
Fitness    = 1.4091019376092528
...
Generation = 200
Fitness    = 1.4091019376092528
```

The prediction outcome:

```
Ground Truth:
array([[1., 0.],
[0., 1.],
[0., 1.],
...,
[0., 1.],
[1., 0.],
[0., 1.]], dtype=float32)

Without GA:
Predictions : 
[[0.9889404  0.00634338]
[0.03020517 0.9684899 ]
[0.28220823 0.76921546]
...
[0.08805525 0.92023355]
[0.9115724  0.08401334]
[0.15908712 0.8055146 ]]

With PyGAD GA:
Predictions : 
[[0.4274468  0.47953305]
[0.40091008 0.38568377]
[0.3937818  0.41261795]
...
[0.3366004  0.43762493]
[0.43253532 0.4112898 ]
[0.40255183 0.4059006 ]]
```

The Fitness Score remained the same after 200 generations had passed, and final model accuracy was below 50%, meaning it's worse than random guessing. I guess my model weights just weren't being trained at all. When I trained the same NN model without ga using binary crossentropy as the loss function (which is also used in the GA fitness function), it worked. I could see the accuracy going up every epoch, and the final acc was above 90%; however, when I tried to use the PyGAD library to train the model with genetic algorithm, it wouldn't work. Is the problem on the NN model or the fitness function I use? I've tried changing the model structure and some hyper parameters I can use in the PyGAD library, such as mutation type or number of parents mating, but nothing seems to be working for me.

Edit: I've tried to create the nn model, and made prediction without any training. Then I ran the ga_instance.run() code to train the model with ga (still, fitness wasn't going up at all), then made prediction with that supposedly trained model, the prediction output with and without ga training are the same, meaning there was no better prediction found in the process of ga. Why does this happen?

I print the ga solutions' fitness for every generation, and I can see there are different set of fitness scores being produced every generation (with very slight improvement on fitness score every generation), meaning the ga is indeed generating different outputs, but they are just a lot worse than the model's initial weight. Even after many generations, no solution better than the initial weight is produced. Does it mean that I just need a lot more generations (like thousands of them) to get better solutions? Or there is something wrong with the fitness function I choose making the improving progress that slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model has large number of parameters (>6.1M). Only the embedding layer has 6M for itself. For a number of parameters like that, the genetic algorithm is expected to take much time for training the model. It does not mean you made a problem. I already tried working with a huge CNN before and there was a progress but very small.

According to the capabilities of your machine, you should increase the number of solutions as much as possible. Also use as many generation as possible.

Thanks for using [PyGAD](https://pygad.readthedocs.io)!

Comment: Thank you for replying. After doing some research, now I understand this machine requires a lot of time to train if I use genetic algorithm. I will get onto it, thank you!